# Receive or retrieve new video uploads on TikTok with Node.js

Tags: node.js, tiktok

I was looking for a way to receive notifications for new uploads on a TikTok profile in my Node.js application. A WebSocket or a Webhook, similar to Twitch, would have been convenient, but it doesn't seem to exist for TikTok.

I also found this API: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/display-api-overview/, but to get the latest uploaded videos, the user must authenticate in my application, whereas I need to retrieve the videos without requiring authentication.

Do you know of any alternative solutions? Another API perhaps? Or an example of polling for this specific case, although I would prefer not to use it as it consumes a lot of resources.